# how to use rails-autoprefixer in Sinatra app?

Tags: css, sinatra, autoprefixer

I can't make autoprefixer work. It is called, but no result in my css code.

There are instructions for Sinatra app here - https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails

application.rb

```
class Application < Sinatra::Base
  # Load path and gems/bundler
  $LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  require "bundler"
  Bundler.require
  register Sinatra::AssetPipeline
  assets = Sprockets::Environment.new
  AutoprefixerRails.install(assets)    
  ### other

  # Actual Rails Assets integration, everything else is Sprockets
  if defined?(RailsAssets)
    RailsAssets.load_paths.each do |path|
      settings.sprockets.append_path(path)
    end
  end
end
```

I looked into gem source and found such examples:

```
@assets = Sprockets::Environment.new
@assets.append_path(@dir.join('app/app/assets/stylesheets'))
AutoprefixerRails.install(@assets, browsers: ['chrome 25'])
```

or

```
@dir = Pathname(__FILE__).dirname
@css = @dir.join('app/app/assets/stylesheets/test.css').read
AutoprefixerRails.process(@css)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, Sprockets is not configured properly.
`Sprockets::Enviroment` takes a block, using which the paths to the
assets needs to be configured. This is the folder structure I used for
this example:

```
├── app.rb
├── assets
│   ├── some_more_styles.css
│   └── styles.css
└── views
    └── index.erb
```

Here is how I configured the Sprockets environment:

```
# app.rb
require 'autoprefixer-rails'

assets = Sprockets::Environment.new do |env|
  # This ensures sprockets can find the CSS files
  env.append_path "assets"
end

AutoprefixerRails.install(assets)
```

There's one more step to get Sprockets to work with Sinatra. Each of the
assets need to be routed manually. For instance, if the `index.erb` has
a `<link>` tag that tries to load a file at path `/assets/styles.css`,
that route will result in a 404 Not Found error if it's not defined in
`app.rb`. To avoid those 404s, define the route like so:

```
# app.rb
get '/assets/*' do
  # The env["PATH_INFO"] results in the string '/assets/styles.css' in
  # our example. We need to remove the '/assets' part since Sprockets
  # will take care of appending it when invoked on the next line.

  env["PATH_INFO"].sub!("/assets", "")
  assets.call(env)
end
```

I've uploaded the full code to
https://gist.github.com/kgrz/5caf63f827e5a6181597cefae484a515 for your
reference. This in turn is based on the [Sinatra Recipes article on
Sprockets](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/asset_management/sprockets?#article)

Comment: Thanks for help.
I forgot to mention, that I'm using RailsAssets. 
I have scss files which are compiled into css.
How to use autoprefixer it in this case ?

Comment: I'm not famiilar with RailsAssets, so can't help much there :(